# CodeIgniter 2.3 fails to upload PNG files only

Tags: php, codeigniter

JPG's work just fine, PNG's fail upload.

I can't for the life of me figure out why.

I'm using CodeIgniter 2.3.2.

MIMES.php

```
'jpg'   =>  array('image/jpeg', 'image/pjpeg'),
'png'   =>  array('image/png', 'image/x-png'),
```

Model Code:

```
  $new_file_name = $this->db->insert_id();
  $config['upload_path'] = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/images/mainimg/';
  $config['file_name'] = $new_file_name;
  $config['allowed_types'] = 'png|gif|jpg|jpeg';
  $this->load->library('upload', $config);
  $this->upload->initialize($config);
  if(! $this->upload->do_upload('Image'))
  {
    echo $config['upload_path'] . $this->upload->file_name;
    $errors = $this->upload->display_errors();
    echo $errors;
    exit(-1);
  }
```

Error:

```
/Users/Me/Documents/Project/html/images/mainimg/317.png
The filetype you are attempting to upload is not allowed.
```

Comment: If you dump `$this->upload->data()`, what is the file type of the file you're trying to upload shown as?

Comment: image/jpeg... what the heck!

Comment: @JLeft if you post this as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score -2):

```
$config['allowed_types'] = 'png|gif|jpg|jpeg|pjpeg|x-png'
```

Comment: please provide explanation with your answer

Comment: Allowed_ types basically give permission to upload different types of files like PNG allowed only that file which have extension .png . similarly others .....